# Iniciar un AutoCompleteTextView con un objeto predeterminado

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando con un formulario para editar la información de un cliente, el formulario tiene tres `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Cada `AutoCompleteTextView` tiene un adaptador que recibe un `List<Object>`. Como es un formulario para editar necesita que cada `AutoCompleteTextView` se inicie con el `Object` que esté guardado en la base de datos.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView acContactos = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.acContactos);
final List<Contacto> contactos = new ContactoSQL(getContext()).getContactos();
final ArrayAdapter contactosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contacto>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, contactos);
acContactos.setAdapter(contactosAdapter);
acContactos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       contacto = (Contacto) contactosAdapter.getItem(position);
   }
});
```

Por ejemplo, el cliente seleccionado tiene el contacto con id 8, que en el `List<Object>` tiene el index 7 y ese `Contacto` debería estar seleccionado por defecto al abrir el formulario para editar el Cliente.

Quedo atento a sus comentarios y ayuda, saludos.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, te refieres a que el AutoCompleteTextView debe mostrar por default un valor dependiendo del cliente seleccionado?

Comment: Sí, el cliente se selecciona de un `RecyclerView` con el listado de clientes, voy a la BD a buscar la información del cliente seleccionado, y relleno el formulario con la información del cliente.

Comment: ok obteniendo la información de ese cliente para que utilizas el AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: Cuando creo un Cliente tiene muchos contactos (más de 50) y eso los busco con un `AutoCompleteTextView` luego obtengo el contacto seleccionado `OnItemClick` junto con el resto de información del cliente desde el formulario y lo guardo en la DB. La información del Cliente se puede editar, entonces cuando se abre el formulario para editar (es el mismo formulario para guardar) como ya existe un contacto asociado a ese cliente, debe estar por default en el `AutoCompleteTextView` en el recuadro donde se escribe el texto a buscar.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta y comentame que resultado tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es correcto, únicamente tienes que agregar

```
acContactos.setThreshold(1);
```

para que al escribir un carácter se muestre alguno de los nombres de los contactos, esa debe ser la razón por la cual no se mostraba algún nombre (Considerando que `contactos` contiene los objetos requeridos).

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView acContactos = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.acContactos);
    final List<Contacto> contactos = new ContactoSQL(getContext()).getContactos();
    final ArrayAdapter contactosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contacto>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, contactos);
    acContactos.setAdapter(contactosAdapter);
    acContactos.setThreshold(1);  //* agregar!
    acContactos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          contacto = (Contacto) contactosAdapter.getItem(position);

       }
    });
```